# listviewのスクロールバーを制御したいです。

Tags: c#, visual-studio

お世話になっております。
縦スクロールのみのlistviewがあります。

listviewのスクロールバーを制御したいのですが
どのように制御すれば良いのでしょうか？

`AutoScrollPosition`を用いて制御するのだとは思いますが、

```
 AutoScrollPosition =  new Point(0,0);
```

これでは反応がありませんでした。

こちらならなんとか動かないかと思いましたが
こちらもダメでした。`this`指定なので当たり前かもしれませんが、、、

```
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,0);
```

ご教授いただければ助かります。
どうぞよろしくおねがいいたします。

visual studio Express2015 64bit

Comment: [スクロールバー付きのクライアント領域のマウス座標を取得するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36003/4236)は`Form`クラスについての質問と見受けられたためそれを踏まえて回答しました。`Form`クラスに対する回答をそのまま別クラスである`ListView`クラスに適用しようとしないでください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Formの方は無事出来ております。
勘違いしてしまい申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

制御したいのはlistviewのスクロールバー(添付画像の**内側**のスクロールバー)でしょうか？
`AutoScrollPosition`で制御できるのはフォームのスクロールバー(添付画像の**外側**のスクロールバー)です。

[image: スクロールバー付きのスクリーンショット]

lisviewのスクロールバーを制御する場合は下記のように`EnsureVisible`を使用するのがお手軽です。

```
listView1.EnsureVisible(0);  //先頭の項目を表示
```